# Add Fields to Field Group programatically

Tags: entities

I have used "Field Group" module and created some groups in backend. Now i want to programatically add a field to the group.  How can I do that.

I am using Hook_form_alter, I have noticed that every field has an 'und'attribute in which the field group it belongs to is listed, but if a create and 'und' array and add a field group name to it, it does not work.

How should I do it?

Comment: You can use the field_group API.  Checkout hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter() (https://www.drupal.org/node/1017962)

Answer (score 21):

This is a bit old, but I wanted to do the same thing and couldn't find an answer on the web. I ended up figuring it out by myself.

Let's suppose you created a field group through the CMS interface with the name "group_product_fields". You added some fields to that group.

Now you have a new field being included in the form programatically via hook_form_alter. You want to add that field to "group_product_fields". Here is an example of what the field could be:

```
$form['new_product_field'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('New product field'),
  '#description' => t('Description for this new product field'),
);
```

All you need to do now is to add that new field to the field group. To do that add the line below to the hook_form_alter. It can be placed anywhere inside it.

```
$form['#group_children']['new_product_field'] = 'group_product_fields';
```

That's all. You may wish to adjust the field weight for it to be positioned as you want. But in the end this is really simple. :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting after [Programtically add fields to a field group](http://drupal.org/node/1338936#comment-5805462):

```
$groups = field_group_read_groups(array(
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'bundle'      => 'article',
  'mode'   => 'full'
));
$your_group = $groups['node']['article']['form']['group_your_group'];
$your_group->children[] = 'field_your_new_field';
field_group_group_save($your_group);
```

Comment: I want to alter the form!

Comment: Then I don't see why you want to use Field Group module? Just define a fieldset(s) and move your fields there. For example: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/how-do-i-organize-the-input-fields-in-fieldset/13244#13244

Comment: We can use `'mode'   => 'form'` or `'mode'   => 'default'` instead of `'mode'   => 'full'`, or just omit `mode` at all. Any view_mode_name, thanks @Maiq Fash

Comment: This provides a way to re-define field definitions, not to do a form_alter - not what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it worked for you. Because array key name must match with database field name. And They are:

> | entity_type | varchar(32)
> | bundle      | varchar(128)
>
> | mode     | varchar(128)

I have to use following format to get it working. let me know if i am doing something silly here.

```
$groups = field_group_read_groups(array(
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'bundle' => 'bundle type',
  'mode' => 'view_mode_name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at hook_field_group_build_pre_render_alter().

This provides you with an opportunity to change the structure of your groups programmatically.

For example, move the field "example_field" **into** the group "group_example" from the root form element:

```
function EXAMPLE_forms_field_group_build_pre_render_alter(&$form) {
  if (example_condition()) {
    $form['group_example'] = $form['group_example']['example_field'];
    unset($form['example_field']);
    // Further adjustments as necessary
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find your field group machine name in the CMS panel then in your form alter do

```
$form['#group_children']['FIELD_MACHINE_NAME'] = 'GROUP_MACHINE_NAME';
```

for an instanst, I've added a custom field mail into the `User form field group` field group    :

```
$form['#group_children']['mail'] = 'group_user_form_field_group';
```