# How do I programmatically add a field to an existing fieldset that's part of the user entity?

Tags: 7, entities

I'd like to know how to add a field to an existing fieldset in a user entity

I've seen this example:

Add Fields to Field Group programatically
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/71902/1082

```
$groups = field_group_read_groups(array(
    'name' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'article',
    'view_mode' => 'full'));
  $your_group = $groups['node']['article']['form']['group_your_group'];
  $your_group->children[] = 'field_your_new_field';
  field_group_group_save($your_group);
```

But I'm unsure what to supply for 'name' and 'bundle' and also what to supply for the line

```
$your_group = $groups['node']['article']['form']['group_your_group'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try hook_form_alter. try this may it helpful to you.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Check your form-ID 
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    // Creating custom field
    $form['new_field'] = array(
      '#weight' => 4,
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('New Field Name'),
    );
  }
  // Attach to the existing group
  // Suppose group machine-name is group_general
  $form['#group_children']['new_field'] = 'group_general';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, here is what worked for me:
in `hook_form_alter`,

```
 $form['#fieldgroups']['group_name']->children[] = 'field_name';
```

Where '`#fieldgroups`' is the actual name of the $form element, and 'group_name' is the machine name of your fieldset, and 'field_name' is the name of the field you want to insert.

This was for a commerce product form...not sure how it works attaching it to a user entity.

Answer (score 1):

I used a different method based on your opening code:

```
$groups = field_group_read_groups(array(
 'entity_type' => 'node',
 'bundle'      => 'article',
 'mode'   => 'form'
));
$your_group = $groups['node']['article']['form']['my_group'];
$your_group->children[] = 'field_event';
field_group_group_save($your_group);
```